# Error sending Magento 2 Products to Ebay with M2E

Tags: m2e, m2epro, ebay

I'm trying to send an item to see how the extension works, but I get this error and I wondered if there is a way to solve this issue.
The error message that I get is the following :

> Input data for <Item.ShippingDetails> tag is invalid or missing. Please read the API documentation.

In the screenshot, the message is in german, I know that M2E have a support team and I contacted them already, but I just want to know how to solve this issue by myself .

[image]